# Proving that, in an finite set, if intersection is equal to $1$ or $0$, then there is not more than $n$ subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

Ok, this seems like a hard question and I never saw anything like this before:

> Let $N$ be a set with $n$ elements. Let $X_{1}, \dots, X_{m},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{m} \subseteq N$, where when $1 \leq i,j \leq m $, if $i\neq j$ then $|X_{i}\cap Y_{j}|=1$ and $|X_{i} \cap Y_{i}|=0$. Prove that $m\leq n$.

So, I was thinking in use some kind of matrix operations, since the usage of $i,j$ injects in my brain some kind of thinking of matrix theory, but I can't proceed. I've even tried to insert some group theory inside, but I couldn't either.

If somebody has some text where this result was proved, I'll be glad to take a look aswell!

Any help with this will be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might as well let $N = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$.  Let $X$ be the $m \times n$ matrix with element $x_{ij}=1 \iff j \in X_i, 0$ otherwise.  Similarly, let $Y$ be the $n \times m$ matrix with element $y_{ji} = 1 \iff j \in Y_i, 0$ otherwise.  Then $XY= E- I$, where $E$ is the $m \times m$ matrix with every entry $1$, and $I$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix.

But $\operatorname{rank}(XY) \leq n$ because $\operatorname{rank} (X) \leq n$, and $E - I$ is non-singular for $m \gt 1$ (because $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $E$, which has eigenvalues $m$ with multiplicity $1$ and $0$ with multiplicity $m-1$), so $E-I = XY$ has rank $m$.  Thus, $m \leq n$.